# PHP Cronjob -- permission denied?

Tags: php, cron

So, I set up a cronjob to run the following command:

`php /var/www/path/to/cron/do-stuff.php`

The path is correct. The directory is owned by `www-data`.

The script does the following:

```
chdir( getcwd() );
echo shell_exec('whoami');

$handle = fopen(uniqid('TEST_') . '.tst');
fwrite($handle, 'foo');
fclose($handle);
```

This is the output I get when trying to run the cron job:

```
www-data
PHP Warning:  fopen(TEST_4e15266d09fa2.tst): failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

Yet when doing this from shell with `su www-data` -- the script executes just fine and produces the test file without a hiccup.

Any idea why this might be?

EDIT: I guess the `su www-data` is probably unnecessary, because php will run however it runs, but I tried that just in case. The cron and script is executed as `www-data` though, as you can see from the output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried putting the full path in the fopen function instead of just the filename?

Comment: Bingo! I'm a moron. `getcwd` was reporting `/usr/share/webmin/cron`.

Answer (score 2):

The cron job handles PATH in a quite different way. 
The same script that usually works when it is called from the command line could return a permission error like this when it is called from crontab if you don't specify the PATH.

Try to change the line:

```
$handle = fopen(uniqid('TEST_') . '.tst');
```

in something like this:

```
$handle = fopen('/var/www/vhosts/yourpath/'.uniqid('TEST_') . '.tst');
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I am confident that even though this is in a cron, PHP itself still runs as it's default user (what that is can vary, of course) and this cannot reasonably be changed. I may be wrong. Try grouping the directory to the PHP system user (apache?) and giving group write permissions. Then see if that works.

Comment: I though `www-data` was the php user? I mean, that's what `whoami` shows. I just don't understand how the script can be blocked in one instance and not in the latter.

Comment: Which user is running the cron? ..?

Comment: www-data -- turns out it was getcwd that was the problem.